# ssis config file not overwriting design time values

Tags: ssis

Have followed directions from multiple sources for setting up an XML config file to allow a package to overwrite the design time database and server selections in BIDS. No matter how I set up and though BIDS reports it is reading the config file, it runs with the design time selections. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify. Give us examples and attempts to solve the issue

Comment: I have a very simple application. It reads a flat file, does a lookup to check for a value on the test database, and either writes to a match or no match output file. The test database table accessed by the lookup has a value of 5 in it while the production version of the same table does not. When running with a config file that has been modified to point to the production server and database, it still runs against the test database. The only way I can get it to run against the production database is to open up the lookup and redirect it to the production database connection. manager.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a long shot but check for another config file in the file location you used at design time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a setting like below: 
"Have DW connection details in a XML file. And rest all configuration parameters is stored in the DW dbo.SSISConfigurations Table."

Then make sure DW Connection setting is the topmost configuration in your Package Configuration List. Otherwise, it will not read the configuration from the SSIS Config table. For detail please go to this link:

http://debpriyaseal.blogspot.com/2015/12/ssis-not-reading-from-config-table.html